# Automating Flutter Web App with Cypress: select element other than flt-glass-pane

Tags: flutter, cypress

When I try to select elements using the cypress test runner, no matter what I click the element is the `flt-glass-pane`. How do I get cypress to ignore this or to go deeper?

Answer (score 0):

`<flt-glass-pane>` has a shadow root, you go deeper with `.shadow()`

```js
cy.get('flt-glass-pane')
  .shadow()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('flt-scene-host')
    ...
  })
```

or add it globally in config

**cypress.config**

```js
{
  ...
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

But note `<canvas>` inside is impenetrable to Cypress commands. Best you can do is visual comparison.

For example

- [Applitools: Visual AI Powered Test Automation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0_D5F0p2xY) shows interacting via click
- [Testing an HTML canvas with Cypress](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/canvas/) shows regression testing via snapshot